# Improving question on championship privilege

Tags: discussion, closing, editing, deleted-questions

Re [When does/do a champion/s 'defend' vs start from scratch? Difference between 'champion' and '(recurring) tournament winner'?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/399388/when-does-do-a-champion-s-defend-vs-start-from-scratch-difference-between-ch)

[Sorean](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/7639/sorean) suggests

> This is probably better suited for english.stackexchange.com or linguistics.stackexchange.com The question (as I read it) is more about asking about word usage in scenarios rather than anything to do with video games/esports specifically.

Fine I suppose maybe question #2 (see below) but question #1 maybe ok?

I mean to ask like... For whatever gaming championships there are csgo, valorant, LoL, DotA, etc, sometimes champions will get full privilege, partial privilege and no privilege.

2 questions:

1. How does any federation of any game decide which of the 3 privileges a champion gets?
2. Sometimes tournaments are called championships. Sometimes tournaments have privilege for the previous tournament winner/championship. What is the point of calling a tournament a championship if the champion doesn't have any privilege?

**Question for this meta post**: How do you suggest I go about asking the above?

Guess re my question #1: I believe this is on-topic. Afaik, csgo champions get no privilege at all. Are all csgo championships like this? What about valorant? LoL? DotA? If there's even a single tournament of a single game on-topic in this SE site, then I wanna know what's up. And if they're all the same (no championship privilege) then why?

Guess re my question #2: I...guess this is on-topic. And if so, then well I thought #2 would be like an easy to follow up to #1 but well guess I'll have to split it?

Comment: [Very related question on Sports Meta](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1062/improving-question-on-championship-privilege). [Another very related question on Board and Card Games Meta](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2100/improving-question-on-championship-privilege)

Comment: You seem to have cross-posted duplicate questions across multiple SE sites. That is not in accordance with SE policy, as per the Meta SE FAQ post: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/162827)

Comment: @galacticninja it can be specific. i can ask about poker only on exactly 1, chess on exactly 1, basketball on exactly 1, csgo on exactly 1. So then what's the cross post problem? It's like asking the same question on christianity SE and judaism SE but changing the religion. is that against SE rules?

Answer (score 6):

**Don't crosspost a question to multiple SE sites, that will make your questions too broad since you're making them fit multiple topic areas. Make your question *specific* to the topic area of the SE site you think is most applicable to post your question on.**

I've noticed you all around different SE sites, copy-pasting the exact same question to multiple SE sites (crossposting). I've also noticed that most of the questions you crossposted have been closed. Crossposting is not in accordance with Stack Exchange policy, as per the Meta SE FAQ post: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/162827) — which is probably the main reason why your crossposted questions are being closed.

> Ask the question on the site you think is most applicable. Each site is focused on a **specific topic area** and it's important to [respect the community](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/03/22/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/).

Instead of crossposting the same question to multiple SE sites, choose only *one* SE site that you think is most applicable to post your question on. Make your question *specific* to the SE site you're posting on. Don't crosspost.

Because you crossposted the exact same question to multiple SE sites, your [question here in Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/399388/4797) includes mentions of tennis, chess, pro wrestling, etc., well exceeding Arqade's topic area. The examples you gave are about pro wrestling and chess. Since Arqade is a video game site, those topics are blatantly off-topic here.

***If* you think Arqade *is* the *SE site that is most applicable to your question*, then you should edit it to be *more specific*. What specific *video game* or what specific *esport* league or tournament, would you like to ask about? Also, give *video game*-specific or *esports*-specific examples. Remove mention of video game-irrelevant and other off-topic content in your question, e.g., chess, pro wrestling, etc.**

Answer (score 4):

I believe you already got your answers in the comments:

- Sub-question 1 is about games and sports in general, and not in particular about video games.
- Sub-question 2 is, indeed, a matter of interpretation and definition, which is not something we discuss here, and, as Sorean pointed out in the comments on the closed question, more suitable for [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/).

Other problems your original question had were:

- It consists of two distinct questions (➝ '*Needs more focus*').
- It is honestly hard to follow the scenario(s) you are presenting (➝ '*Needs details or clarity*').
  This is something that is mainly caused by unclear phrasing and structure, but can also be mended through communication.
- It is very broad. I think (but am sports-ignorant) that different organizations will have different privileges for defenders of titles (which could get your question closed for either of the reasons mentioned above).

Comment: lol ok so AGAIN why don't i just ask 1 post for csgo and then 1 post for valorant, 1 post for whatever else competitive gaming there is, etc (at least for #1)?

Comment: wait another thing: is it forbidden to ask about comparing games in general eg why does csgo get to do this while valorant doesn't? It doesn't have to be about championships. It can be about anything. Maybe say doping penalties or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

The question is just... incredibly broad. And at the end of the day, its just the decision of the TO.

Usually, 'defending your title' is that you won the last title of that tournament or tournament series.

In CSGO, a major winner will usually be defending their title at the next major; not whatever the next tournament is.

In hockey, its always who won the last stanley cup, because its the only tournament series those teams play in.

Comment: 'In CSGO, a major winner will usually be defending their title at the next major; not whatever the next tournament is.

In hockey, its always who won the last stanley cup, because its the only tournament series those teams play in.' --> lol thanks so why can't this be an answer then? (Forget Q2 i think i figured it out. Just focus on Q1.)

Comment: That is true for CSGO, but not valorant or any other esport. And only true for the major circuit. Your question is still incredibly broad.